# SQL-запрос подсчета количества продуктов по категориям

Tags: sql, sql-server

помогите, пожалуйста, сделать запрос:

Есть две таблицы:

```
         Products                  Categories                                                  
ProductId  CaregoryId      CategoryId       Name     
1              1                1           Cat1    
2              1                2           Cat2
3              1                3           Cat3
4              2                           
5              2
```

Нужно сделать запрос подсчета количества продуктов по категориям. В запросе учесть категории, в которых нет продуктов.

Мое частичное решение:

```
 SELECT Name AS Category,  COUNT(*) AS Products FROM Categories, Products
 WHERE Products.CategoryId = Categories.CategoryId
 OR Categories.CategoryId NOT IN (SELECT CategoryId FROM Products)
 GROUP BY Name
```

Результат:

```
Category       Products
Cat1              3 
Cat2              2
Cat3              5
```

Но для категории Cat3 в столбце Products не должно быть 5, потому что в Cat3 нет продуктов. Как откорректировать запрос или сделать по-другому? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Замените неявное соединение (FROM a, b) на явное (FROM a [LEFT|INNER] JOIN b) и все получится.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.[Name], COUNT(ProductId) OVER(PARTITION BY C.[NAME])
  FROM Categories c
  LEFT JOIN Products p 
    ON c.CaregoryId = p.CaregoryId
  ORDER BY c.[Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH 
Products
AS (
    SELECT ProductId, CaregoryId
    FROM (
    VALUES 
        (1, 1),
        (2, 1),
        (3, 1),
        (4, 2),
        (5, 2)
    ) v(ProductId, CaregoryId)
),
Categories
AS (
    SELECT CaregoryId, [Name]
    FROM (
    VALUES 
        (1, 'Cat1'),
        (2, 'Cat2'),
        (3, 'Cat3')
    ) v(CaregoryId, [Name])
)
SELECT c.[Name], COUNT(ProductId)
FROM Categories c
    LEFT JOIN Products p ON c.CaregoryId = p.CaregoryId
GROUP BY c.[Name]
ORDER BY c.[Name]
```